# Retrofit2 проблемка с примером

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

Ребята,хочу научиться пользоваться библиотекой Retrofit. Выполняю пример один и выбивает мне постоянно одну ошибку из этого кода:

```
App.getApi().getData("bash", 50).enqueue(new Callback<List<AnekdotGetSet>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<AnekdotGetSet>> call, Response<List<AnekdotGetSet>> response) {
        posts.addAll(response.body());
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<AnekdotGetSet>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred during networking111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

При запуске прилоги показывает мне Toast из onFailure. Что здесь не так?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<AnekdotGetSet> posts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        posts = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.posts_recycle_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        PostsAdapter adapter = new PostsAdapter(posts);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

//        try {
//            Response response = App.getApi().getData("bash", 50).execute();
//        } catch (IOException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }

        App.getApi().getData("bash", 50).enqueue(new Callback<List<AnekdotGetSet>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<AnekdotGetSet>> call, Response<List<AnekdotGetSet>> response) {
                posts.addAll(response.body());
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<AnekdotGetSet>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred during networking111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

App:

```
public class App extends Application {

    static Api api;
    private Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String BASE_URL="umorili.herokuapp.com";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www.umori.li/") //Базовая часть адреса
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Конвертер, необходимый для преобразования JSON'а в объекты
                .build();
        api = retrofit.create(Api.class); //Создаем объект, при помощи которого будем выполнять запросы
    }
//    private App(){
//        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
//                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
//                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
//                .build();
//        api=retrofit.create(Api.class);
//    }

    public static Api getApi(){
        return api;
    }
}
```

Api:

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("/api/get")
    Call<List<AnekdotGetSet>> getData(@Query("name") String resourceName, @Query("num") int count);

}
```

PostsAdapter:

```
public class PostsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<AnekdotGetSet> posts;

    public PostsAdapter(List<AnekdotGetSet> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AnekdotGetSet post = posts.get(position);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            holder.post.setText(Html.fromHtml(post.getElementPureHtml(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
        } else {
            holder.post.setText(Html.fromHtml(post.getElementPureHtml()));
        }
        holder.site.setText(post.getSite());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (posts == null)
            return 0;
        return posts.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView post;
        TextView site;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            post = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postitem_post);
            site = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postitem_site);
        }
    }
}
```

Изменив адрес,на тот,который писали в комменты пришла новая ошибка:

```
10-02 14:06:04.904 4852-4852/com.example.my.weather E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.example.my.weather, PID: 4852
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:188)
                                                                          at com.example.my.weather.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                                          at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Ругается на эту строку: posts.addAll(response.body());

Get/Set:

```
public class AnekdotGetSet {

    @SerializedName("site")
    @Expose
    private String site;
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("desc")
    @Expose
    private String desc;
    @SerializedName("link")
    @Expose
    private Object link;
    @SerializedName("elementPureHtml")
    @Expose
    private String elementPureHtml;

    public String getSite() {
        return site;
    }

    public void setSite(String site) {
        this.site = site;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public Object getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(Object link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getElementPureHtml() {
        return elementPureHtml;
    }

    public void setElementPureHtml(String elementPureHtml) {
        this.elementPureHtml = elementPureHtml;
    }
```

Comment: Добавьте больше информации об ошибке. Что пишет в логи, если сделать `t.printStackTrace()` в `onFailure`?

Comment: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: @Agrgg обновил вопрос,добавил ошибки

Comment: Ну вот Вам и проблема: в теле ответа Вам вовсе не джсон приходит. Попробуйте добавить логгирование (вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45706709/3100967) рецепт как), посмотрите, что Вам на самом деле в теле ответа приходит.

Comment: @Agrgg по примеру всё делал,тут вроде работает) https://habrahabr.ru/post/314028/

Comment: Так что же всё-таки в теле ответа приходит, если не джсон?

Comment: Html там, в котором сказано, что хост www.umori.li отдаст данные только браузеру. Для получения с приложения нужно использовать другой хост 'http://umorili.herokuapp.com

Comment: @shcherbuk Так проблема решилась заменой базового УРЛа? Если что, у Вас в коде есть константа BASE_URL = "umorili.herokuapp.com", но в ретрофит билдер вы передаёте вовсе не эту константу, а строку "http://www.umori.li/"

Comment: @Agrgg обновил вопрос

Comment: @eugeneek новые ошибки после изменения адреса. Обновил вопрос

Comment: @shcherbuk, покажите что сервер отвечает на хапрос. Хотя бы даже просто если в браузере запрос вбить.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб http://www.umori.li/api/get?name=bash&num=50

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а если изменить адрес на тот,который в комментах пишут,то ошибку выбивает при таком запросе

Comment: @shcherbuk Судя по всему у Вас `response.body()` возвращает `null`. То есть или моделька неправильная (что вряд ли, наверное пустой `ArrayList` был бы), или у вас HTTP статус код не 200 (как описано [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33758324/3100967)). Поставьте брейкпоинт в `onResponse`, гляньте, какой у вас HTTP код ответа, проверьте, что возвращает `response.errorBody()`

Comment: @shcherbuk, вот по этому адресу всё работает. `http://umorili.herokuapp.com/api/get?name=bash&num=50` - покажите модель данных. Может там что-то не так

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил

Comment: Моделька вроде правильная. В Вашем случае атрибуты `@SerializedName` и `@Expose` не нужны -- эффект одинаковый, что с ними, что без них. Так какой у вас HTTP статус код и что на самом деле в теле запроса?